# Windows 7 Enterprise Icons on running applications getting mixed up

Tags: windows, icons

I am running Win 7 Enterprise 64 bit, and I have an annoying problem.

As a developer, I typically have several applications open at the same so I can jump back and forth between design documents, web pages, database and code.  I have noticed with Windows 7 that it gets confused and attaches the wrong icon to the program displayed on the start bar.

For example, Windows will give Microsoft SQL Management Console the icon of my text editor, or give my text editor the icon for a folder.  This does not happen on load, but after swapping back and forth a few dozen times.

I find it very annoying!  My searching has revealed that Microsoft has had issues with the icon cache in win 7, but I've not noticed the problem on any program that is not currently running.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I have never seen or heard of this (corrupted IconCache sure, but not icons swapping between task bar entries).  Have you got any 3rd party desktop, taskbar or window managers running?  Does it do it in Safe Mode (or normal mode with all 3rd party start-ups/services disabled)?

Comment: No, no 3rd party desktops or anything.  Just stock 32 bit Windows 7 Enterprise.  It is locked down pretty tightly (I don't have admin rights, even though I am a developer.)  I've not tried to reboot into safe mode.

Comment: @AndrewNeely - 32-bit or 64-bit your original question says its 64-bit ( not that it matters ) just means your question isn't clear.

Comment: It's 64 bit, Sorry. Don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that.